# Laravel multisite solutions

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

I want to make a multisite webpage solution like [Tubmlr](http://www.tumblr.com/). 
Basically all I want to do, is that once my user publish his/her page, it will have an URL like `{username}.domain.com`. I came up with two solutions so far.

.htaccess: `malac.domain.com` will go to `malac.domain.com/user/usrname`

sub-domain-routing:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{username}.domain.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'UserController@published_page');
});
```

My question would be, which one should I use and why? Will I run into any problem in the future?

I do want to store all the static files at one place.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read it all yet, but this seems like a [good tutorial](https://medium.com/laravel-4/26cdc75e4810).
From my own opinion I would use sub-domain-routing. Just because htaccess is not portable to nginx server. But otherwise both would work